# Why FCM Notification not receiving on majority of my client devices?

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my android app, I’m sending push notifications.As You can see in the attachment,Only 32 percent of fcm notifications are received on client device's. Take example of my own client device. I’m not receiving fcm notifications but receiving fcm test notifications (By using FCM token of my device.) This was happening to my device after installing app from play store (release version). 
What can I do to decrease sends/receive ratio on FCM.
Also, please explain why I’m able to receive FCM test notification but not FCM notifications in my app download from play store?
Thanks in advance!!

[attachment of FCM console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhzYc.jpg)

Comment: Please contact Firebase support directly with your observations.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: This is a Firebase support question

Comment: Perhaps this would help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57947042/firebase-cloud-messaging-didnt-see-xiaomi-devices/57951824#57951824