# Device Specific Issue in Receiving Push Notification when App is killed/closed

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

**Lenevo Mobile** not receiving push notification when App is Closed/killed. I have analysed this issue for long time. Tried solutions like removing app from Optimize app List. etc. Please Help me out.

Comment: How do you create messages? Is it a service of your app or external API like FCM?

Comment: Used FCM to send messages

Comment: Probably FirebaseMessagingService is killed by the system and method onMessageReceived is never trigged. You should try to send data payload message which is handle by the system android not by app itself. Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57947042/firebase-cloud-messaging-didnt-see-xiaomi-devices/57951824#57951824

Comment: Used Data Payload Only. ( that is also not receiving in Lenevo mobile)

Answer (score 2):

Lenovo/vivo and some other manufacturers have auto-start feature that disables most apps(except of whitelisted apps like facebook) to start in background, try giving your app permission to auto-start manually in settings

Comment: Can u tell tell me how to enable auto restart feature in Lenovo Tab 3 ?